# javascript get type/instance name

Tags: javascript

Is there a reliable way of getting the instance of a JavaScript object?

For example, relying on the fake '`obj.getInstance()`' function.

```
var T = {
    Q: {
        W: {
           C: function() {}
        }
    } 
};

var x = new T.Q.W.C();
console.log( x.getInstance() === T.Q.W.C); // should output true
```

If this is not part of the ECMA specification, please include browser/node.js support and compatibility in answers.

Comment: I think you have to rephrase the question. `x` *is* an instance and yes, using `new` is pretty reliable to get an instance. Maybe you are looking for `instancof`, to get the type of the instance? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/instanceof

Comment: **TL;DR:** In regards to the actual question in the title ("get type/instance name"), use `Object.getPrototypeOf(instanceName).constructor` to safely access (due to immutability) the object's constructor function, which will be its actual JS type (e.g. the type of its `class`, or just `Object`, `Function`, `Number`, `String`, etc.), and then use `theType.name` to get the string name of said type. For unsafe access, you could simply use `instanceName.constructor`.

Comment: As for the question itself, the example code is sort of poorly framed (though this is not a criticism as obviously one can't be expected to know how to perfectly ask something they're learning about). I think the best you're gonna be able to do with that code is just check for things using `instanceof` like the other comments/answers describe. More likely one would be using `class`es with `extends` for inheritance.

Comment: In that case, use the method I just provided; or, if you want the base class type, you can put a function **inside** the class (can't be set on the `.prototype`) and then use `super.constructor` instead. Note that here you can't use `Object.getPrototypeOf(super)`, because `super` is just a JS keyword. You could then for instance `return` the type from the function. It seems that you can only ever access 1 `super`, the immediate parent, though... Another approach would be to store `this.constructor` or `super.constructor` as a property of each `class`............................................

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**To get a pointer to the instantiating function (which is not a "class", but is the *type*), use `obj.constructor` where `obj` is any object.**

---

In JavaScript there are no classes. As such, there are no class instances in JavaScript. There are only objects. Objects inherit from other objects (their so called prototypes). What you are doing in your code is literally defining an object T, which's attribute Q is another object, which's attribute W is another object, which's attribute C is a function.

When you are "creating a new instance of T.Q.W.C", you are actually only calling the function T.Q.W.C as a constructor. A function called as a constructor will return a new object on which the constructor function was called (that is with `this` beeing the new object, like `constructorFunction.apply(newObject, arguments);`). That returned object will have a hidden property `constructor` which will point to the function that was invoked as a constrcutor to create the object. Additionally there is a language feature which allows you to test if a given function was used as the constructor function for an object using the `instanceof` operator.

So you could do the following:

```
console.log(x instanceof T.Q.W.C);
```

OR

```
console.log(x.constructor === T.Q.W.C);
```

Comment: Next answer answers the asked question.

Answer (score 71):

Only tested on Chrome:

```
function FooBar() {

}

var foobar = new FooBar();

console.log(foobar.constructor.name);  // Prints 'FooBar'
```

Comment: Same with Firefox 102.0. I believe it has worked this way in Firefox for quite some time.

Answer (score 12):

In case anyone is still reading this in 2017:

Be careful about using `obj.constructor`, as it is not an immutable property.

The `instanceof` operator is generally more reliable. You can also use `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)`:

```
var arr = [];
arr instanceof Array; // true
Object.getPrototypeOf(arr); // Array [  ]
Object.getPrototypeOf(arr) === Array.prototype; // true
```

See this useful document on the topic:

https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch5.md

Comment: Note: Let's say `elem` is a `<span>` (`HTMLSpanElement`), then `elem.isPrototypeOf(Element)` => **`false`** whereas `elem instanceof Element` => **`true`**

Comment: See my comments on the question for more regarding this approach...

Answer (score 4):

I had some trouble with this, the solution was:

```
String(x.constructor) === String(T.Q.W.C)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
    get(){ // Method
        for ( var nameOfVariable in window ) 
            if (eval(nameOfVariable +"=== this")) return nameOfVariable;// true if variable name is instace of this
        return "";            
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Be aware that contructor.name cannot be used with minifying (it will be an empty string) - only instanceof can be used here.

Comment: That may have something to do with your build/bundler/optimizer configuration, an instance of an object created with `var obj = new Template()` will have a `obj.constructor.name` property available.